# Load local file during heroku rake task

Tags: heroku, rake

I have an import utility I'd like to use for creating records on heroku.

I want to use that to import data from a file on my development machine without having to check the file into the repository. Is there a way to do this with a rake task or the heroku gem?

I could upload the file in a web form which could time out, or I could store the file on S3, but that seems rather excessive.

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can read from standard in on your machine.

```
heroku run rake whatever <./file
```

Comment: What would be the syntax for accessing this file data within the task definition?

Comment: Note that for larger files (> ~4K) you may need to pass `--no-tty`. See this issue:  https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/issues/1409#issuecomment-243344505

Answer (score 3):

I have found a really simple approach to this is to use gist for input data.  You copy and paste your data into a gist and then pass the link to the raw gist as a param to your rake task.  Then in the rake task you open the remote file.

For example, if you are loading a yaml file:

```
YAML.parse(open(file_name)).to_ruby.with_indifferent_access
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to access local files on your development machine from anything run with `heroku run` (which includes rake tasks, assuming you're on cedar).

I've taken the following approach:

- seed data is stored in the repo and loaded using seed_fu
- Non-seed data is uploaded to S3 via a web form, and linked to a `DataFile` model using paperclip (a little overkill, but I was using it for images elsewhere). I can then use rake tasks or delayed job workers to process the files.  It's definitely a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the heroku database from inside a rake task.

```rb
namespace :data_loader do
  desc "loads data"
  task load_data: :environment do

    if ! ENV['DATABASE_URL'].nil?
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ENV['DATABASE_URL']
    end

    load_my_data( "/local/path/to/huge_file.txt" )

  end
end
```

Then from your local project root, you can run:

```
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my_app) rake data_loader:load_data
```

You just need to change `my_app` to the name of your app, and you may also need to change `DATABASE_URL` to match the name of your database url config var from Heroku.